# Background Services in Cordova Ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I've been working with Ionic v1.x for the past 5 months and currently we're migrating to Angular2/Ionic2, super excited!

There's still one obstacle though that we haven't been able to address. How do we implement background services? I'm aware of a number of plugins out there but none of them is what I'm looking for.

I know we can write our services in Java for instance, but I still haven't found anything useful on the subject. How do I wire up the service with my Ionic app? and how do build the project with PhoneGap or cordova/ionic CLI?

Basically I need a background service that starts after device boot, and it might be running in the background whether the app is open or not, active or suspended. We have a native app so all I need to do now is find a way to wire it up and build my Ionic app.

Any thoughts are appreciated, but I'm especially looking for tutorials, sample codes etc.

Comment: are you searching for  background geolocation ? if you search for this . I can recommend a plugin . but its not free.

Comment: nope I know how to use geolocation services, I need to work with a background service written in Java for Android or Objective-C for iOS. the kind of service that can run after device boot regardless of the app being open/active or not. kinda like windows services. still haven't found any solution, weird. Is it alright then to think that those millions of hybrid apps published over the past few years never used background services?

Comment: Take a look at : https://github.com/Red-Folder/Cordova-Plugin-BackgroundService plugin for BG Services. This 1 too : https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode

Comment: @HardikVaghani thank you! I'll examine these repos and get back to you as soon as possible :) cheers